# EJB timer reliability

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, openejb

I use an openejb `@Resource TimerService` (which injects `org.apache.openejb.core.timer.TimerServiceImpl` I think) to set a recurring task to each second.

```
timerService.createCalendarTimer(new ScheduleExpression()
                                    .hour("*"),
                                    .minute("*"),
                                    .second("1"),
                                    new TimerConfig("timerName",false)
                                    );
```

Initially, the timeouts occure more or less each second, but with time the reliability deteriorates and after several days the deltas between the calls look someting like that:

```
    delta [seconds]     number of occurences
    ----------------------------------------------
    0                   18057
    1                   35084
    2                   2509
    3                   4668
    4                   1869
    5                   2093
    6                   632
    7                   376
    8                   697
    9                   93
    10                  6
    11                  3
    15                  2
    16                  1
    18                  1
    19                  1
    20                  3
    22                  2
    25                  2
    26                  2
    31                  2
    33                  1
    34                  1
    38                  1
```

The function called is not blocking, I don't get any "UnableToAquireLock" exceptions.

How can I ensure that not more then two seconds pass between two sequential calls for the function?

Comment: A couple of questions about usage: 1. An enterprise bean usually creates a timer within a transaction. If this transaction is rolled back, the timer creation also is rolled back. Similarly, if a bean cancels a timer within a transaction that gets rolled back, the timer cancellation is rolled back. In this case, the timer’s duration is reset as if the cancellation had never occurred. Can you check this?

Comment: 2. Are you using a Scheduled bean with one method decorated with Timeout annotation? 3. Can you consider using a simple timer using  timerService.createTimer(...) instead of a timerService.createCalendarTimer (see ref here https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html#bnbpe)

Comment: Can you post your full example code?